# Does Debian collect private data from its users?

Tags: debian

I am wondering if Debian collects data about its users?

Thanks for any pointers to specific programs that collect user data per default.

Comment: If you have the popularity contest enabled, then it collects stats on what packages you use.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This question is about ["Using or administering a *nix desktop or server"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and can be answered by naming software that comes with Debian and collects personally identifiable data per default.

Comment: The basic answer is no, it doesn't and it wouldn't have anywhere to send it to even if it did (there's no private company behind Debian). The details will depend on exactly what Debian you are using, what options you used when installing, what programs you have installed and what you have enabled by default.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor By default, popularity contest package anonymously submit the information. Even if servers along the way might add headers and log info it is droped as soon as it enters the debian system. And even then, there is no debian company to submit information to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian, in general and by policy, avoids gathering any private information of its users:

> [*There is no requirement for anyone who wishes to use Debian to provide the project with any personal information*](https://www.debian.org/legal/privacy)

However, some packages **do** try to collect private information, like Chromium when you log in as a specific user in the browser. But that is actually done by **Google** and not by Debian.

- [Related Debian bug on Chromium](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=792580)
- [Related list of secure Linux distros](https://fossbytes.com/secure-linux-distros-privacy-anonymity/)